# How to print a write value given prolog predicate retuns true?

Tags: prolog

How can I print a statement if a given prolog predicate returns true or false.

```
statement(X,Y) = true -> write("The statement is true").
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You use Prolog as intended (I will use format/2 instead of the write/1)

```
% if statement(X,Y) succeeds, Prolog will continue after the ","
% and call format/2

with_print(X,Y) :- 
   statement(X,Y),
   format("The call succeeds (and the statement is presumably true)",[]).

% if statement(X,Y) fails, Prolog will continue after the ","
% and call format/2

with_print(X,Y) :- 
   \+statement(X,Y),  
   format("The call fails (and the statement is presumably false)",[]).
```

The second clause is dangerous. If use negaion-as-failure `\+` on a goal that has variables that are nonground and visible outside that goal, Prolog may well give you incorrect answers (this is known as "floundering")

Therefore:

```
% if statement(X,Y) succeeds, Prolog will continue after the ","
% and call format/2

with_print(X,Y) :- 
   statement(X,Y),
   format("The call succeeds (and the statement is presumably true)",[]).

% if statement(X,Y) fails, \+statement(X,Y) succeeds and 
% Prolog will continue after the "," and call format/2

with_print(X,Y) :- 
   ground(X),
   ground(Y),
   \+statement(X,Y),  
   format("The call fails (and the statement is presumably false)",[]).

% what do you want to do in this case? it depends

with_print(X,Y) :- 
   (\+ground(X);\+ground(Y)),
   format("I don't know what to do!",[]).
```

Note that we can write this in a simpler way using the cut `!`. This way, one needs to call `statement(X,Y)` only once. This may necessary if the call is expensive or has side-effects, or a matter of aesthetics:

```
% If statement(X,Y) succeeds, Prolog will continue after the ",",
% commit to this clause due to "!", and call format/2

with_print(X,Y) :- 
   statement(X,Y),
   !,   
   format("The call succeeds (and the statement is presumably true)",[]).

% If the call statement(X,Y) in the clause above failed, we arrive here.
% Commit to the clause with "!" after testing for groundedness.

with_print(X,Y) :- 
   ground(X),
   ground(Y),
   !,
   format("The call fails (and the statement is presumably false)",[]).

% What do you want to do in the "else" case? it depends!

with_print(_,_) :- 
   format("I don't know what to do!",[]).
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use if-else.
The prolog program checks if X is equal to Y, if true then print the statement `The statement is true`, else print the statement `The statement is false`.

```
statement(X,Y):-
    (   X==Y ->  
    write('The statement is true');
    write('The statement is false')).
```

**Example:**

```
?- statement(3,3).
The statement is true
1true

?- statement(3,45).
The statement is false
1true
```